# Function for loop stops after 2 loops using Python and selenium

Tags: python, loop, selenium-webdriver, elementos

Eu quero extrair elementos dentro de uma lista de vários elementos que busco pelo selenium em uma página da web. Funciona bem no primeiro Loop, mas depois trava. Aqui está o código:

```
n = 1
trList= driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#table > tbody')
time.sleep(3)    

for tr in trList:
    tdcontact = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#table > tbody > tr:nth-child(' + str(n) + ') > td:nth-child(6) > input[type=text]')    
    valor=tdcontact.get_property("value")
    print ("tdcontact Result = " + tdcontact.text)
    print ("-----------------"+str(n)+"------------------")
    n += 1
```

Como não há erros, não sei o que está acontecendo. Agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: ja acho trlist, para que a necessidade de usar o drive novamente?

Answer (score -1):

Tente adicionar um **sleep** dentro do loop, trate o erro caso ele não encontre o elemento **n** específico, entenda como a página web se comporta ao fazer uma busca por esta query, provavelmente a página está atualizando e seu código não.